# What is going on with the ajax AutoCompleteExtender?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

This really is bizarre. I'm trying to implement the AutoCompleteExtender using a database. I enter the first character, let's say 'T' into the textbox, and the drop down results panel shows all of the page's source code (client side rather than server side), one character per line as seen in the image.

[AutoComplete Results Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZIur.png)

Incidentally, Google Chrome displays this straight away, while IE has a good think about it, saying localhost is not responding because it's running a long script.

If I then select any one of those characters it then displays the correct results beginning with 'T', though replaces the character I typed with whatever I selected.

I pulled the code from a tutorial on codeproject.com and apart from changing the textbox ID and a bit of ADO so it points to my database, it's identical.
I'll include the code. What's going wrong?

Now for some reason, it's not letting me post the code, regardless of how I format, but this is what I used.  [AutoComplete With DataBase and AjaxControlToolkit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201099/AutoComplete-With-DataBase-and-AjaxControlToolkit)

Comment: Generally that seems a pretty messy way to do ajax and autocomplete to me...

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to give answer without seeing the code... try this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchKey" runat="server" Width="350" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtSearchKey_TextChanged" />
<asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="weSearchKey" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtSearchKey" WatermarkText="Search by Name" WatermarkCssClass="watermark" />
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="YourWebMethod" MinimumPrefixLength="3" CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="txtSearchKey" ID="searchExtender" runat="server" FirstRowSelected="false" OnClientItemSelected="GetSelectedId" CompletionListCssClass="completionList" CompletionListItemCssClass="listItem" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="itemHighlighted" CompletionListElementID="divCompletionListElement" />
<input type="hidden" id="hdnSelectedId" name="hdnSelectedId" value="" />
```

Have a javascript method to ensure selected item is captured

```
function GetSelectedId(source, eventArgs) {
    var selectedId = eventArgs.get_value();
    var e = document.getElementById('hdnSelectedId');
    if (e) {
        e.value = selectedId;
    }
}
```

Create a WebMethod in your back end code that is configured in ServiceMethod property of AutoCompleteExtender

```
    [ScriptMethod()]
    [WebMethod]
    public static List<string> YourWebMethod(string prefixText, int count)
    {

        var totalRecords = 0;
        var searchResults = <<get your results here into a list or whatever container>>
        //I used DataTable as a container here for searchResults
        if (searchResults.Rows.Count == 0)
            return new List<string>() { "No result found" };

        //Create a List from your search results and return it
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow searchResult in searchResults.Rows)
            items.Add(AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(searchResult["Name"].ToString(), searchResult["BuilderID"].ToString());

        return items;
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at the page I linked to, my code is essentially that, though I took the animations section out for brevity.